# Add CFNetwork using CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoa, cocoapods, cfnetwork

I am trying to add CFNetwork to my project using Cocoapods instead of adding the library and linking the binary files. I tried:

`pod 'CFNetwork'`

And ran `pod install`. The error I get is:

> [!] Unable to find a pod with name matching `CFNetwork'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is core library, you just can't isolate only `CFNetwork` using cocoa pods.

Comment: Ahh ok. So core libraries aren't available on CocoaPods? Is there a reason for that? Mostly asking from a version control standpoint. I envisioned having all dependencies under Cocoapods, not pushing to the repo, and then running `pod install` to grab all dependencies.

Comment: To use it with CocoaPods you have to isolate only that one class. For that you need source code a.k.a. implementation file. I doubt that you have one :)